# HTTPSで通信をする方法について

Tags: centos, https

今、サーバにSSL証明書を自己証明書として入れました。
サーバ側で作成した秘密鍵とCSRがあります。
その上でサーバに対して他のPC（クライアント側）からHTTPSにて通信をしようと考えています。
その際に、クライアント側（centos7）でHTTPS通信をする為にどうすれば良いでしょうか。
初心者の質問で申し訳ありませんが、秘密鍵やCSRを入れなければいけないのではないかと思いますが、
どのように入れればいいのか教えていただけませんでしょうか。

追記
サーバはWebサーバ（httpd）です。
やりたい事は勉強目的で私の検証環境（閉じているのでインターネットとは接続されていません。私以外にアクセスできません。）でHTTPSのパケットをWiresharkで見たい、というものになります。
イントラなどでの通信をしたい訳では無いので、私の勉強用です。

Comment: まず一口に「サーバ」と言っても色んな役割が考えられるので、**何のサーバなのか** をはっきりさせましょう (恐らくはwebサーバを指しているのかなとは思いますが…)。 / そして HTTPS は "webサーバ" と "クライアント" 間で暗号化されたやり取りを行うプロトコルですが、通常クライアント側では余計なことを意識する必要はありません (スタック・オーバーフローもhttpsですよね？)。 / ssh か何かと勘違いされているような気がします。

Comment: 既に書いてある手順でできるはずです。つまりブラウザ側で何か登録とか設定とかする必要は一切ありません。うまくいかないとしたら原因はすべてサーバ側にあります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結果として何も入れずにHTTPSで通信をしたら出来ました。
curlコマンドでHTTPS通信をする際に、ポートを443で指定せずに行うと、たとえ-sslv2等でSSL通信を指定していたとしてもHTTPS通信は出来ないという注意点がありました。

Answer (score -2):

自己認証局が発行した自己証明書であって、標準的なブラウザが信頼していないもの、つまり俗にいうオレオレ証明書ですよね？　すると [PKI](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AC%E9%96%8B%E9%8D%B5%E5%9F%BA%E7%9B%A4) 的信頼チェーンが結ばれていませんので https://jp.globalsign.com/blog/articles/website_warning_avoidance.html でいう「証明書の発行元が信頼できない」のケースに相当します。なので

- https 通信の機能のうちの１つ、正しい相手と接続されているかの判定が効かない
- https 通信の機能のうちの１つ、暗号化は（おそらく）なされている

という状況になります。さて、これを是正する手段は目的によって異なり

- https 通信ができているかどうかの確認がしたいだけ（実運用はしない）
  このサイトの閲覧を続行するを選んで、正しい表示がなされたら https 通信は成功しています。単にテストであればそれ以上のことをしてはいけません。そっ閉じしましょう。
- この自己証明書をもってイントラネット内 https を運用したい
  推奨しませんが、どうしてもやりたいのであれば、全社員および外部監査業者の両方が納得するような運用体制を作ったうえで、ルート証明書を配布してください。多分運用コストがあわないです。
- この自己証明書をもってインターネットに https ページを公開したい
  PKI の根幹を否定する行為なので、ダメ、絶対、です。あなたの企業の信頼を落とすだけの行為であり全く無意味です。業者から証明書を購入してください。

[何かの入れ方] を解説するのは誤った運用を助長する行為で有害だと個人的には思うのでこれ以上の説明はナシでお願いします。